# Error in REST request for accessing api.ignition.org

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to run an existing environment in Gazebo for my ROS project. Basically I need to do some robot navigation in a predefined environment. After installing all the dependencies and doing the setup of the workspace I try to roslaunch the environment. However, Gazebo opens up an empty environment. That is a problem since there ought to be a large floor with a couple of offices and some obstacles for the robot, as well as the robot itself. I checked the startup initialization and there seems to be a problem with accessing api.ignition.org, as shown in the picture below.

[image: image description]

I tried pinging the server but got no response and after googling it, I realized it was a large storage of models for gazebo, which got me to the conclusion that this error was responsible for an empty environment opening in Gazebo.

I am new to Gazebo and have only a slight experience with ROS so I apologize if I didn't use correct terms for explaining my problem.
I wonder if someone else had a similar problem and if so, is there a way to fix this.
I am using ROS melodic version 1.14.3 and Gazebo version 9.0.0

Thank you for your time and help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/22263/error-in-rest-request-for-accessing-api.ignition.org/) by [TinK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9148/tink/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-04-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

> there seems to be a problem with accessing api.ignition.org

That's a [known issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2607/error-restcc-205-during-startup-gazebo), the Ignition Fuel server is having SSL certificate problems, so requests to https://api.ignitionfuel.org/1.0/models are not going through unless you allow a security exception.

A couple of ways to get rid of the error:

- [Upgrade](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install#Alternativeinstallation:step-by-step) to Gazebo >= 9.1.0, which has Fuel disabled by default.
- Update the server in  `~/.ignition/fuel/config.yaml` from https://api.ignitionfuel.org to https://api.ignitionrobotics.org

> which got me to the conclusion that this error was responsible for an empty environment opening in Gazebo

I wouldn't expect this error message to be causing your models not to load, because Gazebo 9 primarily relies on [gazebo_models](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/). There could be several other reasons for the models not loading.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2